# order of words in a sentence

Tags: translation

I am a beginner in Japanese.

I want to say "There is a car, that I want to show you."

There is a car, should be: 車があります

I want to show you: 私はあなたに見せたい。 (may be? Is this right?)

I want to show you this: 私はあなたにこれを見せたい。

but this sounds really weird to me: 私はあなたに車がありますを見せたい。

What is the right way to say this?

Thank you for reading this far. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

車があります is correct. 見せたい (want to show) is also correct, however, for the sentence 「私はあなたに見せたい」　you would probably want to omit 私は　and you wouldn't say あなた either. 車が見せたいです　would already imply it was you who wanted to show the car to the person you're talking with.

There are several ways one could translate "There is a car, that I want to show you." The way I would probably do it here would be 「(私が)見せたい車があります」 "(I) have a car that I want to show you." You're probably already familiar with sentences like 赤{あか}い車があります "There is a red car", but you can also create *noun-modifying clauses*, in this case, the noun is the car, using verbs as well, so long as the verbs are in the plain/dictionary form. Another example is something like 「昨日｛きのう｝来｛こ｝なかった人は誰｛だれ｝ですか」 "Who was the person who did not come yesterday?"

Comment: I understand your answer and now that I read it, it makes so much sense! Before, I never thought of inversing them :(

Thank you very much for your kind answer and patient explanation!

Comment: "～たい　(want) always takes the particle が instead of を."

this is a great rule to know and very easy to remember. Thank you!